# Django's AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE ( User Profile ) misbehaving

Tags: django, django-templates

The Error -

```
"Caught FieldError while rendering: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field.
 Choices 
are: id, is_active_online, person"
```

The Model -

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'account.UserProfile'

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    person      = models.OneToOneField(User)
    is_active_online = models.NullBooleanField(null = True, default = None)
```

The Origin of the error from a template -

```
{{ user_object.get_profile.is_active_online }}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

> To make use of this feature, define a model with fields for the
>   additional information you'd like to store, or additional methods
>   you'd like to have available, and also add a OneToOneField named user
>   from your model to the User model.

Your `OneToOneField` needs to be named `user`

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa, I'm not sure... I'd check the source for you but time is short right now!